# How to convert mdq.Similarity score to the number of edit operations in MDS, in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, clr, distance, levenshtein-distance

How can I convert the result of `mdq.Similarity` to the [number of edits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) needed for the two words to match. This function is part of Master Data Service (MDS) in Microsoft SQL Server defined as:

```
USE [mds]
ALTER FUNCTION [mdq].[Similarity](@input1 [nvarchar](4000), @input2 [nvarchar](4000), @method [tinyint], @containmentBias [float], @minScoreHint [float])
RETURNS [float] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [Microsoft.MasterDataServices.DataQuality].[Microsoft.MasterDataServices.DataQuality.SqlClr].[Similarity]
```

The two words that are 1 edit away from each other produce different Levenshtein distance, which seems to account for their length (number of characters in the word).

```
SELECT a=mds.mdq.Similarity('a','',0,0,0), 
ab=mds.mdq.Similarity('ab','a',0,0,0), 
abc=mds.mdq.Similarity('abc','ab',0,0,0), 
ac=mds.mdq.Similarity('ac','ab',0,0,0)

a   ab  abc     ac
0   0.5 0.67    0.5
```

Whereas I need it to return 1 in each case because each pair has two words differing by a single edit (insertion, deletion, substitution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Alan's answer, I digged around for normalized Levenshtein distance. Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15616529/3043335) and, apparently, it works swell: denormalized `mdq.Similarity` outputs number of edit operations. So, MDS function computes

> 1- distance(a,b)/max(a.length, b.length)

So, we reverse engineer the original Levenshtein distance as (note the rounding!!):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnLevDist(@a VARCHAR(100), @b VARCHAR(100), @minScoreHint FLOAT=0) 
RETURNS INT AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @scaler REAL = CASE WHEN LEN(@a)>LEN(@b) THEN LEN(@a) ELSE LEN(@b) END
    RETURN ROUND((1.0 - mds.mdq.Similarity(@a, @b, 0, 0, @minScoreHint)) * @scaler, 0)
END
GO

WITH txt AS(
SELECT a='a', b='' 
UNION ALL SELECT a='ab', b='a' 
UNION ALL SELECT a='abc', b='ab' 
UNION ALL SELECT a='ac', b='ab' )
SELECT *, Lev=dbo.fnLevDist(a,b,0), Lev_nmzd=mds.mdq.Similarity(a,b, 0, 0, 0) FROM txt
```

I've retained the `@minScoreHint` parameter in the wrapping function because it can greatly improve performance ([see doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)). The output is then:

```
a   b   Lev Lev_nmzd
a       1   0
ab  a   1   0.5
abc ab  1   0.667
ac  ab  1   0.5
```

So, it's not so bad afterall. Still, I wish that Microsoft has cited the publication they build their machine learning work on. It is already a standard practice for package documentation in Python, R, and other software (GPL or otherwise).

Comment: I've been meaning to play around with this but haven't had a chance yet. Nonetheless, what you did looks absolutely brilliant Oleg.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**

I haven't been able to do anything that useful with this function. The main reason I'm posting this is so that people can access the [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as it does not come up when doing a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=cO37WfC4OsvKjwTNx5zACQ&q=mdq.Similarity&oq=mdq.Similarity&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.127381.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.P3hUJc-W2Sw).

Per msdn, mdq.Similarity:

> Returns a similarity score. This score indicates the similarity
>   between two strings that are compared by a specified match algorithm.

I understand Levenshtein, Jaro, LCSS but, after playing around with this function for many hours, it's hard to do anything useful with it. mdq.Similarity is a dead end IMO.

**This**

```
--Using Levenshtein edit distance algorithm.
SELECT Lev = mdq.Similarity(N'Alexia Geogio', N'Alexandra George', 0, 0.0, 0.0);
--Using Jaccard similarity coefficient algorithm.
SELECT Jacc = mdq.Similarity(N'Alexia Geogio', N'Alexandra George', 1, 0.0, 0.0);
--Using Jaro-Winkler distance algorithm.
SELECT jaro = mdq.Similarity(N'Alexia Geogio', N'Alexandra George', 2, 0.0, 0.0);
--Using longest common subsequence algorithm.
SELECT lcss = mdq.Similarity(N'12345', N'93459', 3, 0.0, 0.0);
```

**Returns**

```
Lev
----------------------
0.5625

Jacc
----------------------
0.269230769230769

jaro
----------------------
0.878846153846154

lcss
----------------------
0.6
```

Comment: Hi Alan. Thanks for the link. Indeed, I failed to find a documentation via Bing, Google, and Yahoo. Isn't there a precise formula on how the Levenshtein is computed in `Similarity`. I could then back out the original edit distance I need. Or, may be there is an author's contact at Microsoft who can bring clarity into what is actually being computed.